# How do I add restricted headers like Expect:100-continue in postman using interceptor

Tags: rest, postman, azure-web-app-service, request-headers, postman-native-app

I am trying to add restricted header(expect-100-continue) to postman post request since I have a huge payload. I did some research and found out that postman ignores restricted headers like(expect) even if you add it to header section.

So I downloaded postman interceptor extension as I read in documentation we can add restricted headers through interceptor, I was able to connect interceptor to postman following documentation but I couldn't find a way to add that header.

How would we add those restricted headers to postman to test?

Note: I just want to let you know backstory of this problem too. we deployed our rest application to azure app services with client certificate enabled. when we hit it with large payload, server is not responding, found out from Microsoft documentation that we have to set expect: 100-continue header if we are sending large payload. just want to test adding the header through postman and see if it works. Below is the link of Microsoft documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/posting-a-large-file-can-fail-if-you-enable-client-certificates

Comment: You can check if this article is helpful to you. https://blog.postman.com/postman-v0-9-6-access-cookies-and-restricted-headers-plus-better-testing/